# How to read the Steam Install Path from the Windows Registry?

Tags: python, windows, registry, steam

I'm trying to develop a simple `Python` program that auto-detect the location of the `steam` installation folder.
I know this info can be found in the Registry following this path:
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Valve\Steam`

*For example:*
How to read info from `InstallPath` `REG_SZ` in order to get:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam`

If anyone can help that would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [[Python.Docs]: winreg - Windows registry access](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html#module-winreg).

Although the question is lacking any attempt of solving the problem on your own, here's an example:

> ```py
> >>> import sys
> >>> import winreg
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> try:
> ...     hkey = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Valve\Steam")
> ... except:
> ...     hkey = None
> ...     print(sys.exc_info())
> ...
> >>> hkey
> <PyHKEY object at 0x00000154FF5D0390>
> >>>
> >>> try:
> ...     steam_path = winreg.QueryValueEx(hkey, "InstallPath")
> ... except:
> ...     steam_path = None
> ...     print(sys.exc_info())
> ...
> >>> steam_path
> ('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam', 1)
> >>> steam_path[0]
> 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam'
> >>> steam_path[1] == winreg.REG_SZ
> True
> >>>
> >>> winreg.CloseKey(hkey)
> ```

**Notes**:

- I had to create the registry entries, as I don't have any *Steam* components installed
- The exception handling is only for demo purposes (given the fact that's in the console), you should elaborate it a bit
- When running from a *032bit* *Python*, you should **remove *\WOW6432Node*** from the key name (and the returned path will be slightly different)